# Add a margin to LinearLayout in Android

Tags: java, android, layoutparams

I have some problems with setting margin!

```
body_content = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.body_content);

int gSLength = 2;
 body_content.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);

for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
   FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this);
   LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 90);
   fl.setLayoutParams(params);

   LinearLayout ll1 = new LinearLayout(this);
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 30);
   params1.setMargins(0, 60, 0, 0);
   ll1.setLayoutParams(params1);
   ll1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.line_down));
   fl.addView(ll1);

   body_content.addView(fl);
}
```

It does not work `params1.setMargins (0, 60, 0, 0);`

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work? Did you try adding padding to the parent?

Comment: change type of `params1` from `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` to `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`

Comment: may be u can use...params1.leftmarin etc..,,

Comment: lc2817
I mean that LinearLayout ll1 does not fall down. I can not do padding for parents, because FrameLayout fl are still bits and pieces that do not require these properties.

Comment: Udaykiran
I tried params1.topMargin = 60 but it does not work either!

Comment: Removed salutations: "Hi" and "Thanks in advance", please don't do that next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Sherif's comment is correct: `params1` should be an instance of `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` and not `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.
The reason is simple: `ll1` is a child of a FrameLayout, so it has to take the layout params for a FrameLayout children.

The second thing is that `FrameLayout`s depend heavily on the `gravity` attribute. When creating a new instance of the layout params for a FrameLayout child, [`gravity` is set to `-1`](http://google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/FrameLayout.java&q=FrameLayout%20package%3aandroid&type=cs&l=451) by default *(which is an invalid value for a gravity)*. And if the child's gravity is set to -1, the whole margin calculation gets [skipped](http://google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/FrameLayout.java&q=FrameLayout%20package%3aandroid&type=cs&l=303) while calculating the layout. Which means any set margin value gets ignored.

So how to fix that? Pretty simple, set a correct value for the gravity when setting a margin:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = 
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 30);
params1.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
params1.setMargins(0, 60, 0, 0);
```

That should work. But your choice of layout dimensions suggests that you want to position the child LinearLayout at the bottom of the FrameLayout. That can be accomplished by setting the gravity to bottom, you can skip setting a margin in this case.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = 
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 30);
params1.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
```