# How can i set margin to a view in another class?

Tags: android, android-layout, constructor

I do a constructer and set some view inside programmatically and add some rule. so When i call constructer i see default view.

Now i want to reach someof this view and change set margin.It is basic i know but i dosent work for me.

Can anybody help?

Part of my constructer:

```
 _photoImgVw = new ImageView(getContext());
    _photoImgVw.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic);
    _photoImgVw.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    _photoImgVw.setMaxWidth(100);
    _photoImgVw.setId(2);


     lp2=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp2.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
        addView(_photoImgVw,lp2);


        LayoutParams lp3=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp3.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,_photoImgVw.getId());
        lp3.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
        addView(_nameTxt,lp3);
```

Call in the activity for change:

```
 facebookPersonView.lp2.setMargins(10,300,100,20);
```

Comment: Can you give some more details please? What is the outer layout in this case? E.g. if it's a FrameLayout, you have to set a correct gravity to make the margins work. I explained that in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154716/add-a-margin-to-linearlayout-in-android/8196227#8196227).

Comment: We need more code than that, how do you instantiate lp2?

Comment: @alexsc my constructer extends RelativeLayout.Are you asking this?

Comment: @DuyguK Yes, after the edit it's clear. Thanks.

Comment: @Blundell i create my constructer and give the name facebookPersonView.I want to reach lp's margin.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the layout params `lp2` are an instance of the class `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `MarginLayoutParams`, or any other subclass of it named `LayoutParams` *(there are quite a few, see the [top of the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html))*.

If the params are an instance of the latter, they won't contain any rules for the RelativeLayout. Which means the parent layout doesn't know where to place the view¹ and therefore can't make any sense out of the margins.

It's best to declare that explicitly in a way like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 
                    = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp2.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
addView(_photoImgVw,lp2);
```

¹ *It will still make it visible in the top-left corner, but it's kind of an undefined state.*